# Select difference/minus between two columns of different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I'm trying to calculate whether a message is seen/unseen and read/unread.

In the `data_chats_parties` table, there are two fields, `last_seen` and `last_read`

In the `data_chats_messages` table, there is one field, `created` that denotes when the message was created.

I need to subtract the timestamp from `last_seen` and `last_read` from the timestamp in `created`.

The query works fine when performing mathematical operations on columns of the same table, but when I use different tables, it returns an empty result.

Here is my existing query:

```
  SELECT
        data_chats.id AS chat,
        data_chats_parties.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(data_chats_parties.id) FROM data_chats_parties
        WHERE data_chats_parties.chat = data_chats.id) AS total_parties,
        data_chats_messages.created AS last_message_created,
        data_chats_messages.author AS last_message_author,
        data_chats_messages.author_type AS last_message_author_type,
        data_chats_messages.message AS last_message,

        (data_chats_messages.created - data_chats_parties.last_seen) AS unseen,
        (data_chats_messages.created - data_chats_parties.last_read) AS unread

      FROM data_chats
        INNER JOIN data_chats_parties ON data_chats_parties.chat=data_chats.id
        LEFT JOIN data_chats_messages ON data_chats_messages.chat=data_chats.id AND data_chats_messages.active=1
      WHERE
        data_chats.active=1 AND
        data_chats_parties.member=1 AND
        data_chats_parties.status >= 1
      GROUP BY data_chats_parties.chat
      ORDER BY last_message_created DESC
```

Assuming this query worked as planned, if `unread` or `unseen` is `> 0` then it is unseen or unread.

Ideally, I could just set `unread` and `unseen` to `1` or `0` rather than varying values, so that sorting would be easier, but if this isn't possible my original method will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html), like so:

```
SELECT
    data_chats.id AS chat,
    data_chats_parties.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(data_chats_parties.id) FROM data_chats_parties
    WHERE data_chats_parties.chat = data_chats.id) AS total_parties,
    data_chats_messages.created AS last_message_created,
    data_chats_messages.author AS last_message_author,
    data_chats_messages.author_type AS last_message_author_type,
    data_chats_messages.message AS last_message,

    IF(data_chats_messages.created > data_chats_parties.last_seen,1,0) AS unseen,
    IF(data_chats_messages.created > data_chats_parties.last_read,1,0) AS unread

  FROM data_chats
    INNER JOIN data_chats_parties ON data_chats_parties.chat=data_chats.id
    LEFT JOIN data_chats_messages ON data_chats_messages.chat=data_chats.id AND data_chats_messages.active=1
  WHERE
    data_chats.active=1 AND
    data_chats_parties.member=1 AND
    data_chats_parties.status >= 1
  GROUP BY data_chats_parties.chat
  ORDER BY last_message_created DESC
```